# In terms of the greenhouse effect, what is the Earth's heat capacity?

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium, climate-science, meteorology

Has the earth’s atmosphere reached an equilibrium at which the input radiation energy roughly equals its output, or is the output significantly lower than the input because the energy is being used to heat up stuff?  In other words – if the atmosphere’s composition remains exactly the same as it is now, will the atmosphere continue getting warmer, or will the temperature remain as it is now?  If Chuck Norris removed all man- and cow-made greenhouse gases from the atmosphere in an instant – would the atmospheric temperature return to "normal" in a few years, or would there be a significant lag due to the high heat capacity of atmosphere, oceans, and land?

Edits to make my question more precise are appreciated.

Comment: Would this be better on Earth sciences SE. https://earthscience.stackexchange.com. And paragraphs are good....:)

Comment: @user198207 thanks, will post it in Earth sciences.  Paragraphs are intrinsically evil and I will stab at them from the depths of hell.